# HashTable - Array changing size in middle of rehashing

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I'm not sure what is going on with my HashTable. But I have it to where if the array is more than half full, then it will rehash and put the non-empty values into a new array of double size. But for some reason mid rehashing, the array seems to revert back to the original size so Im getting and IndexOutofBounds error and I'm not sure why...

Heres the code I got:

```
public class HashTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashTable table = new HashTable(13);
    table.addItem(5, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(23, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(17, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(8,table.theTable);
    table.addItem(24, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(15, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(2, table.theTable);
    table.addItem(46, table.theTable);

    table.displayTable();


}

int size;
int count;
int[] theTable;

static int EMPTY = -1;
static int DELETED = -2;

HashTable(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.count = 0;
    this.theTable = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this.theTable[i] = EMPTY;
    }
}


void addItem(int value, int[] arr) {
    //Check if array is > half full
    int loadSize = size/2;
    if(count > loadSize) {

        rehash();

    }       
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
    System.out.println("Length " + arr.length);

    int index = hasher(value);

    while(arr[index] != EMPTY && arr[index] != DELETED) {
        index++;
        if(index >= arr.length - 1) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    count++;
    arr[index] = value;
}//END addItem

int hasher(int value) {
    return value % size;
}

void rehash() {
    int[] temp = new int[size*2];

    for(int i = 0; i < size*2; i++) {
        temp[i] = EMPTY;
    }
    size = size *2;
    for(int i = 0; i < theTable.length - 1; i++) {
        int value = theTable[i];
        if(value != EMPTY && value != DELETED) {
            this.addItem(value, temp);
        }
    }


    theTable = temp;
}
```

I'm honestly not sure why its going wrong. But when testing in main, once rehash is called, it is outputing that the length and the size are both 26 (doubled). But when trying to add 46, the size says 26 still but then arr.length is now 13...

Comment: `arr` still references the old array after you call `rehash()`. You shouldn't be passing class's internal fields to itself in the first place.

Comment: One bug I can spot is that you keep increasing `count` while re-hashing, so that it will equal twice the number of elements in there.

Comment: Ahh man that is so obvious now lol. Thank you!

Comment: Yep I caught the count issue too. Fixed it right after I posted this lol

Comment: @shmosel what do you mean by not passing class's internal fields to itself?

Comment: You're passing `theTable` to the `addItem()` method instead of letting it use its internal reference. That means `theTable = temp;` does nothing for the rest of the `addItem()` call.

Comment: Ohh okay gotcha. I’ll fix that and give it a try